# Google Analytics URL Builder with WordPress Post IDs

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

Can anyone help me understand if I'm doing this correctly.

I've got a "Related Posts" section at the end of each page on a WordPress site, which loads in 3 posts based on a variety of factors. So, they're dynamic and always changing.

I want the link on those Related Posts to get tracked via Google Analytics. I want to know if they're a valuable asset of the page or not.

So using Google Analytic's URL Builder form: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

I end up with a link like this:

http://mywebsite.com/?p=123&utm_source=Related%20Posts&utm_medium=Post%20Excerpts&utm_campaign=Testing%20Related%20Posts

Then when I add that to my WP site, I can change the `p=123` dynamically by entering in the post ID.

Will this do what I want?

1. Show up as individual URLs in Google Analytics, under one campaign
2. Provide me specifically with the information, "X # of people clicked these URLs".

Even if I can't see which individual URLs were clicked, I just want to know whether people are actually clicking on them or not.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Using utm_'s for measuring internal clicks etc. on site is very very bad idea. Each campaign changing (your utm after link click will change default visitor source and campaign) in GA will start new session! So one visit will split into 2. (avoid this)
2. Events will be the easiest way to measure related post clicks. Docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated. :)